# Catching & re-calling event in custom confirmation box in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a custom confirmation popup which comes when ever user want to navigate from page without saving any detail. & I'm not able to find a right way to do this ?

Basically I have decided to put a function on window.beforeunload = func(e)  event and use 
  e.preventDefault(); this syntax to prevent the redirect , actually the occurrence of event e. Now is there any way to re-fire the same event(It could be page redirect/ submit), If use clicks on the 'Ok' button.

Comment: You tagged Angular.js, Backbone.js, and Knockout.js but this has nothing to do with any of those frameworks.  Removing the tags.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use `event.preventDefault()` in `window.onbeforeunload`. You can only return dialogue for the `onbeforeunload()` function to give to the user.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload

Comment: Mike you did't see my question properly. I clearly wrote that the " I'm not able to find a right way to do this?" Can you suggest any right way of doing this ?

Comment: You may be able to accomplish using the HTML5 History API, but it would be limited by browser support/implementation. It's an unstable thing and poses some security issues and probably won't function how you would want it.

Comment: Ok. So Is there any other way to do this ? basically i wanted to create a custom confirmation box & limitation is that I can't use any plugin or api. I need to write this js by myself. Any way can you suggest ?

Comment: Those are your only two options.